# MVC login stopped working in Firefox only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox

I have a pretty plain MVC site and I have not touched the authorization piece at all. I was working fine in Firefox when I could no longer sign into the site. I tried edge and chrome and both work fine. I've check the cookies in Firefox and they seem fine. There are no messages in the console. I tried switching to Local IIS. I tried restarting browser, Visual Studio and Windows. My other MVC apps work fine in Firefox.

I'm hoping I've missed something obvious. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the login-process, exactly? Are you using OIDC?

Comment: Start a new private/incognito session in both browsers and open their DevTools' Network panels (ensure "Preserve log" is checked!) and compare each browser's requests. Look carefully at the `Set-Cookie` headers in the server-responses and at what cookies are being sent by each request from each browser.

Comment: My bet is on the culprit being Firefox's recent (September 2019) change to restrict third-party cookies  - are you setting a Domain in your `Set-Cookie` responses?

Comment: So, private tab works. So, there is something about the session that's screwed up in normal Firefox. At this point I'm going to try a reset and see if the problem resolves itself. If that doesn't I'll compare the network traffic between private and normal to see where the difference is.